# How to change node save button text?

Tags: 7, forms, nodes

I found a discussion with some methods for d6 here http://drupal.org/node/344802
on how to change the node "Save" button text to sg else.

Any tips for d7? I would prefer to use form api.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

you could use [string overrides](http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) module or use hook:

```
function yourmodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'name_of_form') {
    $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = 'Your button text';
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I only want to change it for a content type so string override is no good. I tried the form alter code but no change. I checked the $form with dpm, but it has no submit array , only a #submit which looks like sg else.

Comment: This worked for me. The $form_id is unique to the submit form of that content type, so it should work.

Comment: for me it was an $form['ajax-submit']['#value'] = 'xyz', but I'm using the afb module to submit a node through a block form.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an example: I have created a module called `change_form_values` and the form ID of my content type is `content_type_test_node_form`:

this work for me in Drupal 7:

```
function change_form_values_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    //dsm($form_id); // to see form ID
    if ($form_id == "content_type_test_node_form") {
    $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = 'New button text';
    }
}
```

this work for me in Drupal 6:

```
function change_form_values_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    //dsm($form['form_id']['#id']);
    if ($form_id == "content_type_test_node_form") {
    $form['buttons']['submit']['#value'] = 'New button text';
    }
}
```

I hope information be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I found the excellent [Node buttons edit](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_buttons_edit) module for this and it works really our of the box using admin. Here is an excerpt about it from the module's project page:

> This is a simple little module that allows one to change the text on the 'Save', 'Preview' and 'Delete' buttons on a node form.

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal7 it's simple just:

```
$form['buttons'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Your desire text here'),
    );
```

Wihtout adicional functions...

Comment: Nah, by that you'ld overwrite the whole button and reset possible other values given originally (`#weight`, `#validate`, `#submit` ...). You'ld better go only for the `#value`, like written in the other answers above.

Comment: i tested with 3 form of my site and all of them are working fine... i guess what you said could be possible if your using some kind of callback function or ajax function related to the button....