# Drupal Submit button for Smart Doc Page

Tags: views, theming, hooks

I have a smart doc page on a drupal based website which has a submit button. From where to edit the submit button?

Comment: I have checked the edit tab but it has all the fields except the submit button.

Comment: Refer  [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/13395/how-to-change-node-save-button-text)

Comment: Hi @ApurvaGupta, your questions needs more clarity in terms of defining what is smart doc page? Is it a content type? custom form? or else? If there is contributed module you are using to get the smart doc?